# Cannon.js Hinge constraint - motor: How to rotate only one body

Tags: cannon.js

Motor feature with setMotorSpeed function will give us a relative speed between two bodies. As the attached image, is there any solution that make the shorter body not vibration at begining and longer body rotate with constant velocity?

[image]

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Do both bodies have to be dynamic?

Comment: Hi, both bodies have to be dynamic.

I intend to use hinge to simulate servoMotor so that there only one body can be rotated, the other will stay unchanged.

The problem is with using hinge, one body can rotate but the other has a small rotation at the beginning (picture above).

Comment: A constraint connecting two dynamic bodies will always add some force/velocity to both bodies. How much depends on the constraint and the mass properties of the bodies. Therefore, you cannot leave one of them fully unchanged.

Comment: thank you @schteppe, you are right.